# two directives creating new inherited and isolated scope - which one does the element get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, I have my own directive that creates isolated scope:

```
angular.module("main", []).directive("makeIsolateScope", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            node: node
        }
    }
});
```

Then I use it along with `ng-repeat` which creates new inherited scope:

```
<li ng-repeat="node in nodes" make-isolate-scope="node">{{node.name}}</li>
```

What scope does the element `li` get?

Comment: I think first ng-repeat creates inherited scope and after that, in that inherited scope another scope is created for the directive.

Comment: @Anita, please see my answer, if interested

Comment: nice answer. The element will be shared in two scopes But at last its the priority at which the sharing depends,I guess.

Comment: I don't think so, since `ng-repeat` has higher priority then my custom directive and it also is defined as `terminal`, so my directive will be compiled as part of `transclusion` process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the element will have two scopes:

- child scope created by ng-repeat directive

  `angular.element(el).scope();`
- isolate scope created by `makeIsolateScope` directive:

  `angular.element(el).isolateScope();`

The order is the following:

1) `ng-repeat`'s compile function is called and all other directives with priority less then `2000` (`ng-repeat's` priority) are not compiled as part of compiling the node. It means that right now `makeIsolateDirective` is not compiled.

2) since `ng-repeat` is defined as `transclude:element`, the entire node is compiled as part of transclusion compilation process and now `makeIsolateDirective` is compiled and its compile function is executed.

3) `ng-repeat`'s linking function is executed which receives $transcludeFn function. This `$transcludeFn` function is executed `n` times receiving cloned dom compiled against the child scope (created by transclusion mechanism) of the parent node:

```
$transclude(function ngRepeatTransclude(clonedDom, scope) {
    // here clonedDom is the clone of the original <li> node
```

4) `makeIsolateBindings`'s linking function is executed with isolated scope, created by this directive. The parent of the scope is a rootScope.

Linking function of other directives, that do not create isolate scope, are executed with child scope, which was used with `$transcludeFn` inside `ng-repeat`'s linking function.

The directives, that create isolate scope and request `$$isolateBindings` from the parent, are evaluated against child scope created by `ng-repeat`'s transclusion mechanism. Here is extract from source code:

```
forEach(isolateScope.$$isolateBindings = newIsolateScopeDirective.$$isolateBindings, function(definition, scopeName) {
...
case '=':
...
lastValue = isolateBindingContext[scopeName] = parentGet(scope); // the scope here is the child's scope created by transclusion
```

[This article](http://triangular.io/blog/transclusion-transcludefn/) is very useful to understand how `$transcludeFn` works.

Answer (score 1):

Every directive has a `priority` number which is a guidance for `$compile`. The default priority number is 0 and `ng-repeat` is 1000. So if you put 1001 as a priority for your directive, it will be compiled in advance, otherwise ng-repeat will be compiled in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, how that is relevant to the question? Is the scope of the directive with highest priority used for the element?

Comment: Scope is linked to the DOM after the DOM being compiled and linked. In another word, the later compiled one will give the scope

Comment: Well, that's not so easy here, I've just started to investigate the matter myself. `ng-repeat` is indeed has higher priority than my directive, however, it's defined as `terminal`, so my directive will not be compiled at all. But then, `ng-repeat` is defined as `transclude:element`, which will probably eventually compile my directive, but I don't know how this will be done at the moment. Let me investigate it a bit more and I think I'll come up with the answer to my own question.

Comment: please see my answer, if interested

Comment: You really dig the hole deep, I like it and sorry for the information of old version

Comment: yep, but your answer got me started digging :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid those kind of headaches, just move your directive inside the `li`..